# A property which is not true for classes

Tags: c++

I am facing the question in below (especially C++)

A property which is not true for classes is that they 
(A)  are removed from memory when not in use. 
(B)  permit data to be hidden from other classes.
(C)  bring together all aspects of an entity in one place. 
(D)  Can closely model objects in the real world.

Could anyone explain me about meaning of that question?
What is property for classes?

I am new in C++, so if this question is posted anywhere, kindly inform me.

Thank you!

Comment: This sort of quiz questions is not suitable for StackOverflow. You are basically asking four questions: (i) Are classes removed from memory when not in use? (ii) Do classes permit data to be hidden from other classes?, etc. Only one of them happens to have the answer "No", while the other three have the answer "Yes". However, they should be asked separately.

Comment: The four things listed as A-D are the property for classes. Your task is probably to determine which of those are true and false.

Comment: A [property](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/property) "is a quality, attribute, or distinctive feature of anything, especially a characteristic attribute such as the density or strength of a material."

Comment: The term "property" here is not asking about a programming "property" (which is a visible bit of data attached to an object), but in the more general sense of a fact about the subject being discussed.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. sorry if that seems blunt, but "I am new in C++" is not an excuse for not trying to determine the validity of those four statements yourself. Do some research on C++ classes, and then, if you have some *concrete* questions, come back and ask those.

Answer (score 3):

In order: No. Yes. Maybe. Hopefully.

Comment: They're all false to me: (A) The class code is still in the process, though object data is supposedly freed on destruction. (B) This is easy to subvert. (C) You'll need several classes as soon as one aspect of the entity is 1-N with the entity (D) Stuff like the circle-ellipse problem shows limits to that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 'circle-ellipse problem', i didn't even know that...

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone explain me about meaning of that question?

The question gives four "properties" (or traits) of things:

- a) are removed from memory when not in use.
- b) permit data to be hidden from other classes.
- c) bring together all aspects of an entity in one place.
- d) can closely model objects in the real world.

Your task is to identify at least one of those four choices which does not apply to the programming concept called a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is asking about (not necessarily in this order):

1. Real-world modeling
2. Garbage collection
3. Encapsulation
4. Interfaces